# Como vaciar los datos de un formulario con JavaScript

Tags: php, javascript

tengo el siguiente formulario: en html proceso los datos con PHP y relleno filas por medio del boton + con JavaScript.

index.php

```
<script>
// nuevo método para eliminar la fila, recibe como parámetro el botón presionado 
// y navega hasta el nodo de la fila para eliminarla

 function eliminarFilatre(boton){
 // navegar hasta el nodo fila
 fila = boton.parentNode.parentNode;
 // navegar al nodo superior de la fila y borrar la fila
 fila.parentNode.removeChild(fila);


}
    function guardar(){

        var _pos = document.getElementById("pos").value;
        var _nrosf = document.getElementById("nrosf").value;

        var fila="<tr><td>"+
            "<input type='text' name='pos[]' value='"+_pos+"' readonly>"+
            "</td><td>"+
            "<input type='text' name='nrosf[]' value='"+_nrosf+"' readonly>"+
            "</td></tr>" +          

 // botón que llama al método eliminar fila y pasa como parámetro
 // el botón
"<td><button onclick='eliminarFilatre(this)'>-</button></td>" ;

        var btn = document.createElement("TR");
        btn.innerHTML=fila;
        document.getElementById("tablita").appendChild(btn);
    }

</script>




<table id="tabla1">
<tr>        
    <td>Campo 1:</td>   
    <td><select id="pos">
    <option></option>
    <option value="1">1</option> 
    <option value="2">2</option>    
    </select></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Campo 2:</td>
<td><input type="text" id="nrosf"/></td>
</tr>
</table>

<button onclick="guardar()">+</button>



<table class="table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                   <th scope="col">Campo 1</th>
                   <th scope="col">Campo 2</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody id="tablita">

            </tbody>
        </table>
```

El problema es que cuando le presiono el boton + el me deja los campos 1 y 2 llenos en la tabla1 lo que estoy buscando hacer es que al presionar el boton + y llevar los datos al JavaScript que la tabla1 automaticamente deje todos los campos nuevamente en blanco.

Se puede hacer allí mismo con JavaScript?
De que manera lo podría hacer?

Cualquie ayuda podria ser de gran utilidad para mi, muchas gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Existe un input tipo `reset`, si lo pones dentro de un formulario su accion predeterminada sin tener que codificar nada es la de resetear todo los valores de un formulario a su estado original:

```css
input{
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<form>
  
  <input type = "text" placeholder = "nombre">
  <input type = "text" placeholder = "apellido">
  <input type = "number" placeholder = "edad">
  
  <button type = "submit">enviar</button>
  <button type = "reset">resetear formulario!</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Esta muy bien tu ejemplo @Riven pero se podria resetear el formulario automaticamente una vez se presione el boton + al pasar las variables por el JavaScript?

Comment: Ya logre hacerlo muchas gracias.

Comment: de nada @estrada recuerda que si mi respuesta te fue de ayuda puedes darla como aceptada dandole click al boton que parece un chulo ;3